# Druid - Spell slots vs spells prepared

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, spell-slots

Do I understand this correctly about a Level 1 Druid in 5e

with Wisdom modifier of zero, s/he can only prepare 1 spell despite having 2 slots from which to cast ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, that is correct

[Druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid) spell preparation is determined by their Wisdom modifier plus spell level:

> You prepare the list of druid spells that are available for you to cast, choosing from the druid spell list. When you do so, choose a number of druid spells equal to your Wisdom modifier + your druid level (minimum of one spell). The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

In your case, you have:
WisMod(0)+Level(1)=1

Wisdom is the primary stat for a Druid. Having a suboptimal Wisdom is a choice, but this is a consequence of that choice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes your wisdom and experience level let you prepare only 1 spell, which you can cast twice besides your cantrips which are at will. Even better if you were to choose a spell with a ritual tag you could spend 10 minutes plus the casting time and cast infinite times, saving the 2 spell slots for a rapid cast. Per the PHB.

Comment: Ah.. I didn't consider that the single prepared prepared spell could be cast twice

Comment: @RogerMungo: It's different from some older editions, in which casters had to choose which spell to prepare in each slot at the time they prepared their spells. In 5e, they simply choose which ones to prepare in general (or, for known casters, they choose which spell(s) to learn/swap on level up), and can cast any prepared (or known) spell in any spell slot of that spell level or higher.